# Wireless WAP Roaming on Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, wifi

I have an Ubuntu server that connects to the network over wireless. Since it obviously doesn't have Gnome's NetworkManager I have to configure everthing manually.

I've got it sucessfully connecting to the network but when the connection gets interupted instead of roaming to a different WAP it just disconnects. This is obviously bad but I have no idea how to make it roam.

Self-Help thorugh googling has been difficult since no one does this (for good reasons), everything I've found has been for a full desktop, not a server. While I'm totally against installing Gnome, I would prefer not to.

Is there any "command line" equivelent to NetworkManager that roams WAPs when the one its connected to times out?

**Note: I'm not interested in "Do not use wireless" answers.** I would normally never do this but this is a unique case. Just please answer the given question

Comment: +1. I am also looking for the answer or direction. I use ratpoison as window manager and do not use any full furnished desktop. So I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: We've had a few questions about command line alternatives to NM: [All commands that should be used to connect to wifi in command line](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9818) [Command line join of password protected wireless networks in Ubuntu, Arch Linux, or other distros?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2480) and more. I don't know how they handle roaming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others reference, I found that `wpa_supplicant` was the best (only?) option. Took a while to configure it but it worked.

The only issue that prevented me from using and eventually scrapping the project was due to my unique situation: I [needed to change the MAC address](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26126/spoofed-mac-address-ignored-by-wpa-supplicant). Apparently `wpa_supplicant` completely ignores a spoofed MAC address.

Since 99% of people don't care about spoofing MAC addresses, `wpa_supplicant` works.