# Spoofed MAC address ignored by wpa_supplicant?

Tags: ubuntu, wpa-supplicant, spoofing

I'm using wpa_supplicant to power my wireless card in my Ubuntu Server (yes I know wireless in a server is bad, but this is a special case) since it has the ability to automatically roam WAPs instead of just dying. However it seems my spoofed MAC address is being ignored

Here's the important part in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    hwaddress 00:11:22:55:55:D1
    wpa-driver madwifi
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

As you can see, `hwaddress` is defined there but wpa_supplicant doesn't seem to care and just uses the actual hardware address

Is there any way to have wpa_supplicant use a spoofed MAC address instead of the real MAC address?

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem. [/etc/network/interfaces Manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man5/interfaces.5.html) says for dhcp method:

> `hwaddress class address`
>
> > Hardware Address. class is one of **ether**, **ax25**, **ARCnet**  or
> >     **netrom**. address is dependent on this choice.

then maybe the problem is the *class* option. I'll try it.
Other option is not supported by firmware.

Answer (score 2):

Do one of these:

1. Instead of using `hwaddress`, try using `pre-up ifconfig wlan0 hw ether 00:11:22:55:55:D1`
    This may not actually have been required, but I found that on my bonded interface, `hwaddress` did not work, the above `ifconfig` did.
2. I would recommend you either create a bonded interface or a bridge (if bridge, you should be using `bridge_hw 00:11:22:55:55:D1` instead of the `hwaddress` (and make sure you have bridge-utils installed).  Then you add this to your wlan0 stanza: `wpa-bridge br0` (if using a bridge interface named br0): this results in wpa_supplicant using the hardware address of the bridge/bonded interface while authenticating (it appears to be equivalent to using the -b command-line option for the wpa_supplicant)

   ```
   auto wlan0
   iface wlan0 inet manual
       wpa-driver madwifi
       wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
       # we want wpa_supplicant to authenticate using a different MAC
       # ...from http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1515788
       # ...equivalent when running wpa_supplicant directly is the -b option
       wpa-bridge br0

   auto br0
   iface br0 inet dhcp
       bridge_ports wlan0
       # bridge-utils will use the directive below
       bridge_hw 00:11:22:55:55:D1
   ```

Comment: "pre-up ip link set dev wlan0 address 00:13:ef:60:19:31" saved me, thanks

Answer (score 1):

This operation needs to be supported by the (hard|firm)ware. Are you certain that yours does? I've seen lots of chipsets that don't allow that kind of thing.

Comment: Are you sure? I don't think this needs firmware support, but OS will feed the packet with mac address stored in memory(the faked one)

Comment: @warl0ck: AFAIUI, the (hard|firm)ware may automatically overwrite the ether address. Although I admit, I am not sure ;-)

Comment: Just tried wpa_supplicant with my Intel 5100 agn card .. works with fake address, not sure if it's hardware support ...

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in `man interfaces`, `hwaddress` is an option which can be used only with `static` addressing method, and not `dhcp`.

Also, this is the correct syntax for this option:

```
hwaddress class address
    Hardware Address. class is one of ether, ax25, ARCnet or netrom. address is dependent on this choice.
```

Comment: That same syntax works just fine on the other dhcp'd eth0 interface. So I don't think that's the problem